# How to duck (lower volume) of other apps when I play media on my app Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

So, I have been trying to make an audio player app, which will play some music tunes. But if there is something that's already being played in background, then it should duck its audio and allow my app to play its tunes. Is this possible in flutter? I m using audioplayers plugin for playing audio. I have also tried using audio_session plugin. It works to some extent. Like when I m playing music in background, I open my demo app and press play button to play my music tunes, then the background music pauses and my app plays the tune. But after its completion, the music doesn't resumes. Is there any other plugin that i should try ?

Comment: Check my Answe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045070/play-audio-and-duck-music-that-s-playing-in-the-background-in-flutter/68771851#68771851