# Play audio and duck music that’s playing in the background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

really need your help over here.
In my flutter app a short audio should be played when user presses a button,
But when I call play() on the audio player my background music ( Apple Music, soundcloud, etc..) is stopped.
Actual wanted behaviour is lowering the volume of the background music while the audio is playing.
I’ve tried to use the audio session plugin and create new session,
It does work and duck my background music when I activate the audio session, but after activating and calling play on the audio player, it’s just stops the music again.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

Use audio_session plugin. and set configuration according to your requirement.

To activate session, Use this:-

await session.setActive(true);(just before you are all set to play the audio)

await session.setActive(false);(just after you played the audio).(I think you are missing this line)

Please check following Configuration(for duck others):

```
session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
      avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playback,
      avAudioSessionCategoryOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers,
      avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.defaultMode,
      avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy: AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
      avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
      androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
        contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.music,
        flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
        usage: AndroidAudioUsage.media,
      ),
      androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gainTransientMayDuck,
      androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true,
    ));
```

**Note:** Never test this functionality on simulators.Use real devices.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Package - [just_audio_background](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background)

This package plugs into just_audio to add background playback support and remote controls (notification, lock screen, headset buttons, smart watches, Android Auto, and CarPlay). It supports the simple use case where an app has a single AudioPlayer instance.

If your app has more complex requirements, it is recommended that you instead use the audio_service package directly (which just_audio_background is internally built on). This will give you greater control over which buttons to display in the notification and how you want them to behave, while also allowing you to use multiple audio player instances.